# Are all Blood and Fairborn powers inherited?

Tags: the-bastard-son-the-devil-himself

On *The Bastard Son and the Devil Himself*, it seems as if any child of two witches is a witch, and the same goes for Fairborn witches and Blood witches. Almost all the specific powers that we see fit as well: Soul and his brother were both plant witches, Nathan's mother was a potion-maker because her mother was a potion-maker, and Nathan himself was a heart eater because his father was a heart eater and his grandmother before that.

However, Jessica has the power of shapeshifting despite neither her mother nor her mother's husband having this power (but her father need not be her mother's husband), and Annalise seemingly has the power of undoing despite her father having plant magic and her mother having water magic (but it *is* exceedingly suspicious that she says her mother never uses her powers).

Are all powers inherited from some parent or other? Or are random powers possible?